# Dropdown menu to appear outside of div

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I want to put a button dropdown menu inside the info window on my google map api, however, when I click the button to activate the dropdown, it appears inside the info window and not outside which makes the info window scrollable.

Info window code:

```
var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-25.363882,131.044922);
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 4,
    center: myLatlng
  };

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

  var contentString = 
      `<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown Example
  <span class="caret"></span></button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a href="#">HTML</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">CSS</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">JavaScript</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>`;

  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
      content: contentString
  });

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: myLatlng,
      map: map,
      title: 'Uluru (Ayers Rock)',
//    zIndex: Math.round(myLatlng.lat() * -100000) << 5
  });
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    infowindow.setContent(contentString);
    infowindow.open(map,marker);
  });
```

Here is a demo: https://jsfiddle.net/zr52yo18/

I would like the dropdown menu to appear outside the info window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following CSS and it will work.

```
div.gm-style-iw {
  overflow: visible !important;
  padding: 20px !important;
}
div.gm-style-iw-d{
  overflow: visible !important;
}
```

Here is the demo: https://jsfiddle.net/gxay38dz/

Comment: yeah but if the list becomes large then it wouldn't work

Comment: I have updated my answer and fiddle link, you can try this and it will work.